# How to go to a specific URL base on the choices in dropdown and checkbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have this code that when users select a specific value it will go to that URL. But i only have the HTML part.

For example:

Urgency = High ||
Impact = Site/Dept ||
Platform = Unix & Windows

When they click submit they will go to a URL base on those choices

It is like High + Site/Dept + Unix & Windows = URL1.... and so on.

I only have the HTML codes i found during my research but i'm not that good in javascript so i can't seems to find the logic on how to make this work.

Also I'm using sharepoint webpart Content Editor

I can't add the code here so i just put it on the link below

[Link for the code](https://shrib.com/#e_Ok.aCtVyaON9PJzYBt)

Sample conditions:

I hope the below conditions answers your question. But it is a lot so i gave a few examples

Urgency & Impact = Show All; Platform = All Checked => Homepage

Urgency = High & Impact = Show All; Platform = All Checked => URL1

Urgency = Low & Impact = Show All; Platform = All Checked => URL2

Urgency = Show All & Impact = Site/Dept; Platform = All Checked => URL3

Urgency = Show All & Impact = Multiple Users; Platform = All Checked => URL4

Urgency & Impact = Show All; Platform = Unix&Windows => URL5

Comment: Can you please specify all the conditions for the urls?

Comment: Hi Harshal i added the conditions. I hope it answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example code for your reference.

```
<div>Urgency</div>
<select id="urgencyMenu">
  <option selected="selected" value="Show All">Show All</option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
  <option value="Low">Low</option>
</select>
<div>Impact</div>
<select id="impactMenu">
    <option selected="selected" value="Show All">Show All</option>
    <option value="Site/Dept">Site/Dept</option>
    <option value="Multiple Users">Multiple Users</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div>Platform</div> 
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Unix">Unix
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows">Windows
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Network">Network<br><br>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="SubmitClicked()" id="go" value="Submit">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitClicked(){
    var urgency = $("#urgencyMenu").val();
    var impact = $("#impactMenu").val();
    var platform = $("input[name='platform']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();    
    var url="https://homepage";
    if(urgency=="Show All"&&impact=="Show All"&&platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        url="https://homepage";
    }
    if(urgency=="High"&&impact=="Show All"&&platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        url="https://url1";
    }
    if(urgency=="Low"&&impact=="Show All"&&platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        url="http://url2";
    }
    if(urgency=="Show All"&&impact=="Site/Dept"&&platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        url="https://url3";
    }
    if(urgency=="Show All"&&impact=="Multiple Users"&&platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        url="https://url4";
    }
    if(urgency=="Show All"&&impact=="Show All"&&platform=="Unix,Windows"){
        url="https://url5";
    }   
    window.location.href=url;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This worked as i like. Thanks a alot

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. Let me know if you need any help.

```
<div>Urgency</div>
<select id="urgencyMenu">
  <option selected="selected">Show All</option>
  <option>High</option>
  <option>Low</option>
</select>
<div>Impact</div>
<select id="impactMenu">
    <option selected="selected">Show All</option>
    <option>Site/Dept</option>
    <option>Multiple Users</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="platformMenu">
    <div>Platform</div> 
    <input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Unix">Unix
    <input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows">Windows
    <input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Network">Network<br><br>
</div>
<input type="button" onsubmit="SubmitClicked()" id="go" value="Submit">


<script>
//function called when submit button is clicked
function SubmitClicked(){
    var urgencyElement = document.getElementById("urgencyMenu");
    var impactElement = document.getElementById("impactMenu");    

    var selectedUrgency = urgencyElement.options[urgencyElement.selectedIndex];

    var selectedImpact = impactElement.options[impactElement.selectedIndex];

    var platformElementChoices = document.querySelectorAll("#platformMenu input[type='checkbox']:checked");

    //function to check checkbox values = unix & windows (this function can be dynamic with some modifications)
    function checkPlatform(platformElementChoices){
        var vw = true;
        for(var i=0;i < platformElementChoices.length; i++){
            var currCheckbox = platformElementChoices[i];
            if(currCheckbox.value != "Network"){
                vw = true;
            }
            else{
                vw = false;
                break;
            }
        }            
        return vw;
    }

    if(selectedUrgency.value == "High" && selectedImpact.value == "Show All" && platformElementChoices.length == 3){
        window.location.href = URL1; //enter url as string between 2 quotes
    }
    else if(selectedUrgency.value == "Low" && selectedImpact.value == "Show All" && platformElementChoices.length == 3){
        window.location.href = URL2; //enter url as string between 2 quotes
    }
    else if(selectedUrgency.value == "Show All" && selectedImpact.value == "Site/Dept" && platformElementChoices.length == 3){
        window.location.href = URL3; //enter url as string between 2 quotes
    }
    else if(selectedUrgency.value == "Show All" && selectedImpact.value == "Multiple Users" && platformElementChoices.length == 3){
        window.location.href = URL4; //enter url as string between 2 quotes
    }
    else if(selectedUrgency.value == "Show All" && selectedImpact.value == "Show All" && checkPlatform(platformElementChoices)){
        window.location.href = URL4; //enter url as string between 2 quotes
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = homepageURL;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I edited the url enclosing it in quotes. But it is not redirecting to the URL i inputted.

Comment: Is it going in any condition? or redirecting to homepage at least? or is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: check the updated answer. I had missed the '.href' after 'window.location'

Comment: Thanks for your help Harshal.